# Rails gem acts_as_list, scoping the position to the user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-list

I am using Rails 4 and the ActsAsList gem to give our Project model a position. Projects can be owned my one user, and collaborated on with many users. When a user re-orders their projects, it affects the project order for the collaborators as an unintended side-effect. Is there a way around this?

Comment: You can use the `scope` option on the `acts_as_list` gem and give it a symbol of the column name that you want it to scope to. https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/blob/master/README.md#example It sounds like you have the position on the wrong table though. Without seeing your models it’s hard to tell for sure, but I would say that your project shouldn’t have a position column but instead the join table between projects and collaborators should. This will allow you to scope the acts_as_list on the collaborators_projects table to collaborator_id (given the join table idea).

Comment: Also for what it’s worth, I use the acts as list gem at work as well. We have photos on vehicles and the position is scoped to the vehicle id so that each vehicle has its own set of photo positions.

Comment: Hey @Nate thanks so much for your input. After reading the docs I wasn't quite sure how to use a scope but your explanation makes it very clear. I will give that a try, thanks!

Comment: No problem! Obviously if you end up having more questions about it, feel free to update this question with your new findings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** 
Based on @nate's suggestion, I moved the `:position` column from the `Project` model to the `Collaboration` model which is the join table between `Project` and `User`. Then I included `acts_as_list scope: :user_id` on the `Collaboration` model and removed it from the `Project` model. Now each `user` has `projects` through `collaborations` and the position of each `project` is scoped to the `user`.